# Add multiple checkbox caption in List box in User Form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwLbZ.png)

Many thanks for your reply, Please find attached a picture of the user form I Got the data in the list box by some other ways no I am facing an issue to update and edit the data. I am trying to call the data from Listbox to textbox and checkboxes by below code for Editing.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 'UPDATE LISBOX DATA
Dim p As Integer

Me.ComboBoxitem.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 1)

For p = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount < 1
      
Me.CheckBoxSmall.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)
Me.CheckBoxMedium.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)
Me.CheckBoxLarge.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)
Me.CheckBoXL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)
Me.CheckBoXXL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)
Me.CheckBoXXXL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 3)

Me.txtsmallqty.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)
Me.TextBoxmedium.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)
Me.TextBoxlarge.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)
Me.TextBoXL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)
Me.TextBoxxL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)
Me.TextBoxxxL.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 4)

Next
Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(Me.ListBox1.ListIndex, 0)

End Sub
```

and for  update the data in excel sheet after editing ,  I am using below code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click() ' Update Data
Dim L As Long
Dim th As Worksheet
Set th = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
L = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(Me.TextBox1.Value), th.Range("A1:A1000"), 0)

th.Range("B" & L) = Me.ComboBoxitem.Value
th.Range("D" & L) = Me.CheckBoxSmall.Value
th.Range("D" & L) = Me.CheckBoxMedium.Value
th.Range("D" & L).Value = Me.CheckBoxLarge.Value
th.Range("D" & L).Value = Me.CheckBoXL.Value
th.Range("D" & L).Value = Me.CheckBoXXL.Value
th.Range("D" & L).Value = Me.CheckBoXXXL.Value

th.Range("E" & L) = Me.txtsmallqty.Value
th.Range("E" & L) = Me.TextBoxmedium.Value
th.Range("E" & L) = Me.TextBoxlarge.Value
th.Range("E" & L) = Me.TextBoXL.Value
th.Range("E" & L) = Me.TextBoxxL.Value
th.Range("E" & L) = Me.TextBoxxxL.Value
     
Me.CheckBoxSmall.Value = False
Me.CheckBoxMedium.Value = False
Me.CheckBoxLarge.Value = False
Me.CheckBoXL.Value = False

Me.CheckBoXXL.Value = False
Me.CheckBoXXXL.Value = False
Me.txtsmallqty.Value = ""
Me.TextBoxmedium.Value = ""
Me.TextBoxlarge.Value = ""
Me.TextBoXL.Value = ""
Me.TextBoxxL.Value = ""
Me.TextBoxxxL.Value = ""
Me.TextBox1.Value = ""

End Sub
```

*Addition due to comment:*

> "I am trying to pull Listbox data in 6 checkboxes and 6 text boxes from the first code mention above, the Issue I am facing from this code, shows only data from the first line of Listbox to all text boxes and checkboxes.
> By the mean of the second code I have to update data in excel sheet."

But I am not able to get the perfect result, you are requested to please review the above Code and let me know where I am Mistaking.

Your Kind Response will be Highly Appreciated.

Comment: Listbox indexes are zero based, so you would need to use `.ListCount - 1` instead - with that said, your code is just overwriting the value of `.List(x, 1)` (the last row) with each line that sets it, so it's not accomplishing much of anything. Not really sure what you trying to accomplish here, but it does not look like a standard interface, which means it will most likely just confuse your users.

Comment: Side note ad) *"you would need to use `.ListCount - 1`"*:  having executed `.AddItem` the *previously* assigned value of `x` actually equals the *current* value of `.ListCount - 1`, so imo this part at least seems to be okay. @braX

Comment: True - overlooked that part, but it still overwrites the value.

Comment: @FreelancingTech What is your target? - Display (e.g. three chosen items like S,M,XXL) ... a) as string `S,M,XXL`  in the 2nd  listbox column (i.e. `(x,1)`), b) S in the 2nd, M into the 3rd and XXL into the 2nd last column, c) add as many rows as there are chosen sizes repeating the name in the 1st column (index `(x,0)`)?

Comment: Hi, I update my question with screenshots and codes.

Comment: @T.M. you are requested to Please review and let me know, what is missing.

Comment: tl;dr What *precisely* is your issue, where exactly do you run into false results or errors? Allow me some hints: Please edit a *clearly defined* question and focus on it; *"I am not able to get the perfect result"* doesn't say anything.  - btw It's no good idea to ask several questions, this may even result in closing the post. See [MCV E](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), an abbreviation for a **M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable *E*xample and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) - @FreelancingTech

Comment: @T.M. Many Thanks for your reply. I am trying to pull Listbox data in 6 checkboxes and 6 text boxes from the first code mention above, The Issue I am facing from this code, shows only data from the first line of Listbox to all text boxes and checkboxes.  by the mean of the second code I have to update data in excel sheet. But its also not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are displaying always six rows per chosen item (corresponding to six sizes of `Small,Medium,...,XXXL`) with item info only in the 1st row, a main issue is to get the correct `.ListIndex` by doubleclicking to any row within the listbox.

- `1.` The start row index `p` (containing the serial# and product name) can be calculated from the currently double clicked `.ListIndex` using an int(eger) division multiplied by six rows to get to the first row (see section 1):

  ```
  p = (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex \ 6) * 6
  ```

> Example: a double click into `.ListIndex` of 0..5 results in the start row index `p = 0`, of 6..11 in `6`, ... - i.e. always returning the first row of a bundle of six rows containing sizes.

- `2.` To avoid endless assignments I defined two variant arrays (`chkboxes` and `txtboxes`) containing the checkbox and textbox names (see section 2). - Another frequently used method consists in enumerating the control names facilitating assignments in a later loop.
- `3.` The 3rd step assigns the listbox'es main info (3a) and the size-related values (3b) to all single controls; the latter action is executed in a *loop* referring to the controls via `Me.Controls(chkboxes(i)).Value` and `Me.Controls(txtboxes(i)).Value`.

The following code example should give you a *start* and allow to finish the 2nd procedure by yourself *(remind: don't overload a post by too many independant questions, focus to one issue :-;)*

```
Private Sub ListBox1_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean) 'UPDATE LISBOX DATA

'1. get the start row containing the serial code,
'  (even if doubleclicked in one of the five following rows)
    Dim p As Long                                ' instead of Integer
    p = (Me.ListBox1.ListIndex \ 6) * 6          ' each item has 6 rows (sizes available)

'2. define arrays containing checkbox|textbox names
    Dim chkboxes, txtboxes
    chkboxes = Split("CheckBoxSmall,CheckBoxMedium,CheckBoxLarge,CheckBoXL,CheckBoXXL,CheckBoXXXL", ",")
    txtboxes = Split("txtsmallqty,TextBoxmedium,TextBoxlarge,TextBoXL,TextBoXXL,TextBoxxxL", ",")

'3. a) write item name & Serial# to corresponding userform controls
    Me.ComboBoxitem.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 1) ' Item name
    Me.TextBox1.Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p, 0)   ' Serial number

'3. b) loop through all six rows representing sizes
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 5                               ' listbox items and both ctrl arrays are 0-based!
        Me.Controls(chkboxes(i)).Value = CBool(Me.ListBox1.List(p + i, 3)) ' 4th column has index 3!
        Me.Controls(txtboxes(i)).Value = Me.ListBox1.List(p + i, 4) ' 5th column has index 3!
    Next i

End Sub
```